# Why can't I disable landscape view in Xcode 6 project?

Tags: xcode

When I click the Landscape checkboxes below to remove them, Xcode (version 6.1.1) just turns them back on. If I go to the Info tab and remove the landscape displays from the arrays there, it just puts them back. The project file is not write protected.

[image]

Comment: what version of Xcode are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the info.plist file is writable.

Open your app's info.plist file.

Find the "Supported interface orientations" entry.

Click the minus button on the entry for the orientation you want to remove.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the question, you'll see I tried that, and it just puts them back. :) Xcode says "LANDSCAPE DAMMIT".

Comment: Oops, didn't realize info tab was the same as the plist

Comment: Actually, they may not be the same. I am referring to the file in the "Supporting Files" directory (that xcode creates automatically). There is a file named "<project name>-Info.plist". Is that what you tried?

Comment: OK! That file was read-only, so clicking the checkboxes failed to change that file. I use Perforce, and Xcode's P4 integration is non-existent, and goes through a "Behavior" that calls a shell script. Thanks, dude!